# HtmlPages deprecated? How to add bundle of cards to Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've been trying to push a bundle of cards to the timeline using the MirrorAPI and found a bit of info on this here [Erroring with Bundle of HTML Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072031/erroring-with-bundle-of-html-pages)

However, the official docs https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline are missing the HtmlPages option. Has it been deprecated? Why?

Is there another way for me to add a bundle like structure to the timeline in one go?

E.g. BundleCover > Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 > each with their own submenu or even all with the same?

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have separate `menuItems` for each card your only option is to add several timeline cards, each with the same `bundleId` and optionally one card with `isBundleCover` set to `true`.  No way to do this with one API request (but you can do a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/glass/batch)).
([More Information from the docs](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/static-cards#bundling_cards))

The `htmlPages` parameter has been replaced with [(semi-)automatic pagination of cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/static-cards#paginating) when the `html` content exceeds the space on one card. So instead of having a list of `htmlPages` which was used previously, you can now have the full content in the `html` property, with some special mark-up to control pagination. This will result in the cover card (i.e. the first html page) to get a `Read more` menu item. All cards will have the same `menuItems` in this case.

Comment: Thank you Scarygami, works like a treat :) Shame, that you can't have different pages with different menu items but this will do for now I think.